# WPF - problem with triggers

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I have two ListViews with trigger that on selected change the background color to dark gray and the foreground color to white.
The problem is that when I select an item in the first listview and then an item in the second listview the item in the first listview foreground doesn't get black again and it stay white.

[image]

the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="190*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="@ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="Content" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" TargetName="Content" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" TargetName="Bd"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="@TextCellTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="@TrubleCellTemplate">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Style="{DynamicResource @ListView}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource @ListViewItemStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TextCellTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="131" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TrubleCellTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Style="{DynamicResource @ListView}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource @ListViewItemStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TextCellTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="131" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TrubleCellTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Just a hunch.. see if adding `x:Shared="false"` to the Style definition (element) in the ResourceDictionary solves your problem.

Comment: @Gishu - thanks but didn't work

Comment: @Erez - Ok. try adding a reverse trigger i.e. when IsSelected="False" or specifying the default state in the Style itself. Triggers can be very annoying when they don't work - I faced one recently - read thru this and see if you get any leads http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2008/05/13/wpf---changing-the-content-of-a-togglebutton-when-checked.aspx

Comment: Maybe because that item in the first ListView is still selected? It's not clear to me if you want to revert to the original style when the item is not selected anymore or simply when the item loses focus (in which case you might want to replace IsSelected with IsFocused)... also just a hunch.

Comment: @Andrei - good catch. missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting interference between two of the Triggers in your template. The first IsSelected Trigger becomes active when you first select the value in ListView #1. This overrides the TextBlock.Foreground value on "Content" from the TemplateBinding to a fixed value of White.

When ListView #1 loses focus to ListView #2 the second trigger (MultiTrigger for IsSelected and IsSelectionActive) is also activated. This causes the Background of "Bd" to be set to a different value (same as the other Trigger) and, because it's declared later in the Triggers collection, overrides the previous Trigger which is still active.

The same should happen for the Foreground setter, but the one in the MultiTrigger is setting the Foreground on the parent control instead of on "Content". Because "Content" is no longer using TemplateBinding to pull in the parent control's Foreground value the first Trigger's White value remains active on the "Content" element.